# Errors when moving angularjs 2 app to centos 7

Tags: angular, installation, rxjs, centos7

I have an AngularJS 2 application with quite a lot of dependencies and I'm trying to install it on my centos server. I have node 6.6 and npm 3.10.3 and when I run npm install, it installs all components except the @angular/core and related @angular files. And then obviously, if I run npm start, everything breaks. It also doesn't install rxjs which is another dependency. 
If I try install any of them I receive an incompatible error.

1. Does someone have any idea why those are not installing?
2. If not, is there a way to build angularjs 2 apps and deploy them to the server without going through the process of npm install and npm start?

[Install Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt97w.png)

[Angular common install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHljk.png)

Thanks everyone for your assistance!

Comment: use special server to run a build and then just upload generated files

Comment: It didn't work still. The final solution was to convert it to an angular cli project and then ng build it.